# PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_object() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,

Tags: php, mysql, database, warnings

This is function where i take data from database:

```
public function model_pobierz_id_regionu_dla_nazwy($sRegion) {
            return $this->oDb->execute('
                    SELECT id 
                    FROM regiony
                    WHERE nazwa="' . $this->oDb->getSecureForm($sRegion) . '"');
        }
```

I have function where i get Warning, how can i delete this Warning:

```
 $iRegion = Database::GetLikeObject($this->oDb->execute($this->oModel->model_pobierz_id_regionu_dla_nazwy($this->oView->aDane['wojewodztwo']))->id);
```

And function GetLikeObject:

```
        public static function GetLikeObject($aData)
        {
            return mysqli_fetch_object($aData);
        }
```

I take return this warning:`PHP Warning:  mysqli_fetch_object() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,`

How i can delete this warning?

Comment: You can eliminate the warning by fixing the problem with your database query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely that when

```
mysqli_fetch_object($aData);
```

is executed `$aData` is `false` because `$this->oDb->execute(...` failed.

All of the mysqli_* function/methods can fail. Be it because of syntax errors, missing permissions or be it something like the admin tripping over the network cable. You *must* always check the the status/return value of your database operations.
If you don't want to put your error handling code after each and every function call switch to exceptions for error reporting.

see  http://docs.php.net/class.mysqli-sql-exception and http://docs.php.net/pdo